# threading.Timer TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, timer, typeerror

I'm trying to write script which execute something after double click CTRL. It works well after first double click, but then I get that error. Also if I press CTRL once and again after timer execute function trigger I'll get same error.

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, threading

press = False

def triger():
    global press
    press=False
    
def something():
    print 'hello'
    
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global press
    if event.Key=='Lcontrol':
        if press:
            something()
            press = False
        else:
            press=True
            threading.Timer(1,triger).start()
            

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Error:

```
hello

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 828
    return _active[_get_ident()]
RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in KeyboardSwitch
    return func(event)
  File "C:\Users\123\Desktop\code\hooks.py", line 20, in OnKeyboardEvent
    threading.Timer(1,triger).start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 731, in Timer
    return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 742, in __init__
    Thread.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 446, in __init__
    self.__daemonic = self._set_daemon()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 470, in _set_daemon
    return current_thread().daemon
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 828, in currentThread
    return _active[_get_ident()]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Answer (score 3):

Acording to the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial) there have to be "return True" at the end of OnKeyboardEvent function. Here's how it looks like.

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global press
    if event.Key=='Lcontrol':
        if press:
            something()
            press = False
        else:
            press=True
            threading.Timer(1,triger).start()
            print 'waiting'
    return True
```